# How to package App.zip artifact in an installer in Github Actions

Tags: unity-game-engine, installation, devops, github-actions

I'm a unity developer, and I am new to devops. I am using Github Actions to make a prototype CI/CD pipeline for a project. Currently I can build and attach the build artifact to a release after every push. When I download this from the release, I get a .zip file with my project in it. This is expected, as it is how Unity builds games natively.

I want to make an installer for the game, so users do not have to open up a .zip file to find the game executable. I have watched a couple videos on how to do this manually using Inno and InstallCreator2, but I do not know how to do this using my CI/CD pipe (nor do I know if either of those technologies would be best for my use case)

Here is my yaml code. I made it following documentation and tutorials. I have a vague idea of what individual lines, steps, and jobs are doing, but my understanding is rudimentary at best. If something is terribly inefficient or otherwise bad, I probably don't know. I have added a couple comments to aid in my own understanding.

TL;DR: What job/ steps do I add to make the .zip output to an installer.exe type file?

EDIT: (updated YAML code) So, over the past day I tried creating an installer with inno on my local machine, and it worked! Pretty neat. Then I quickly descended into madness trying to edit the hardcode fields in the .iss file in my build server using YAML. At the end of the day it seems that it is rather challenging to get Inno itself on the build server (they have some instructions on the Inno github, but I got stuck trying to figure out how to apt-get Embarcadero Delphi.) Additionally, about 8 hours in I had the thought that "maybe trying to change the filepaths on a script generated in windows, so it is compatible with linux isn't the best way to go." Is there a linux-to-windows installer script generator? I was looking at [this](https://www.conjur.org/blog/building-a-windows-installer-from-a-linux-ci-pipeline/) link earlier, but I feel like I am lacking a bunch of information to actually implement it.

```
name: Build project

on: 
  [push] #Comment this in (and add more triggers if you want), to have the job run on the set triggers (instead of manual). if using, might want to have this run on main branch merge only.
  #workflow_dispatch: {} #Comment this in for a manual push button in github actions

jobs:
  buildForAllSupportedPlatforms:
    name: Build for ${{ matrix.targetPlatform }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        targetPlatform:
          #- StandaloneOSX # Build a macOS standalone (Intel 64-bit).
          #- StandaloneWindows # Build a Windows standalone.
          - StandaloneWindows64 # Build a Windows 64-bit standalone.
          #- StandaloneLinux64 # Build a Linux 64-bit standalone.
          #- iOS # Build an iOS player.
          #- Android # Build an Android .apk standalone app.
          #- WebGL # WebGL.
    steps:
      - name: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          lfs: true
      - name: cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: Library
          key: Library-${{ matrix.targetPlatform }}
          restore-keys: Library-
      - name: build unity project
        uses: game-ci/unity-builder@v2
        env:
          UNITY_LICENSE: ${{ secrets.UNITY_LICENSE }}
        with:
          targetPlatform: ${{ matrix.targetPlatform }}
      - name: upload build artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: Build-${{ matrix.targetPlatform }}
          path: build/${{ matrix.targetPlatform }}    
      - name: Set Up Enviorment Varibles for installers
        run: |
          echo "pathStartpoint=$(pwd)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          cd .installer
          echo "installedDirPath=$(pwd)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "appVersion=$(less VersionInfo.txt)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "iconPath=$(ls -d *.ico | tail -n +1 | head -1)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "appId=$(uuidgen)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          cd ../build
          echo "outputDir=$(pwd)" >> $GITHUB_ENV         
      - name: Create Windows Installer using Inno script
        if: matrix.targetPlatform == 'StandaloneWindows64' #Conditional task
        run: |
          cd ${{ env.pathStartpoint }}
          cd build/StandaloneWindows64
          echo 'refactoring build file arrangment for inno file'
          sudo mkdir tempDir1 tempDir2
          sudo mv ${{ matrix.targetPlatform }}_Data /tempDir1
          sudo mv tempDir1 ${{ matrix.targetPlatform }}_Data
          sudo mv MonoBleedingEdge /tempDir2
          sudo mv tempDir2 MonoBleedingEdge
          echo 'finished refactoring build file arrangment'
          echo 'Making a copy of WindowsInstaller64.iss'
          cd ../..
          sudo cp ./.installer/WindowsInstaller64.iss ./build
          echo 'Finished making copy'
          echo 'setting installer values'
          cd ./build
          sudo sed -i 's/#define MyAppName "UNITYWINDOWSBUILD"/#define MyAppName "${{ github.event.repository.name }}"/g' WindowsInstaller64.iss
          echo 'set MyAppName'
          sudo sed -i 's/#define MyAppVersion "1.11"/#define MyAppVersion "${{ env.appVersion }}"/g' WindowsInstaller64.iss
          echo 'set MyAppVersion'
          sudo sed -i 's/AppId={{76999C4F-90E2-49D0-8EF2-C315F16CEAD6}/AppId={{"${{ env.appId }}"}/g' WindowsInstaller64.iss
          echo 'set AppId'
          sudo sed -i 's,LicenseFile=EXAMPLELicense.txt,LicenseFile=${{ env.installedDirPath }}/License.txt,g' WindowsInstaller64.iss
          echo 'set LicenseFile path'
          sudo sed -i 's,InfoBeforeFile=EXAMPLEPreInstall.txt,InfoBeforeFile=${{ env.installedDirPath }}/PreInstall.txt,g' WindowsInstaller64.iss
          echo 'set PreInstallFile path'
          sudo sed -i 's,InfoAfterFile=EXAMPLEPostInstall.txt,InfoAfterFile=${{ env.installedDirPath }}/PostInstall.txt,g' WindowsInstaller64.iss
          echo 'set PostInstallFile path'
          sudo sed -i 's,OutputDir=EXAMPLEDIR,OutputDir=${{ env.outputDir }},g' WindowsInstaller64.iss
          echo 'set Output path'
          sudo sed -i 's,OutputBaseFilename=EXAMPLEPROJ_Setup(x64),OutputBaseFilename=StandaloneWindows_Setup(x64),g' WindowsInstaller64.iss
          echo 'set OutputFile name'
          sudo sed -i 's,SetupIconFile=EXAMPLEICONPATH.ico,SetupIconFile=${{ env.installedDirPath }}/${{ env.iconPath }},g' WindowsInstaller64.iss
          echo 'set Icon file path name'
          sudo sed -i 's,Source: "EXAMPLEPATH/{#MyAppExeName}",Source: "${{ env.pathStartpoint }}/build/StandaloneWindows64/{#MyAppExeName}",g' WindowsInstaller64.iss
          echo 'set executable path'
          sudo sed -i 's,Source: "EXAMPLEPATH/UnityCrashHandler64.exe",Source: "${{ env.pathStartpoint }}/build/StandaloneWindows64/UnityCrashHandler64.exe",g' WindowsInstaller64.iss
          echo 'set Crash Handler path'
          sudo sed -i 's,Source: "EXAMPLEPATH/UnityPlayer.dll",Source: "${{ env.pathStartpoint }}/build/StandaloneWindows64/UnityPlayer.dll",g' WindowsInstaller64.iss
          echo 'set unity player path'
          sudo sed -i 's,Source: "EXAMPLEPATH/StandaloneWindows64_Data/*",Source: "${{ env.pathStartpoint }}/build/StandaloneWindows64/StandaloneWindows64_Data/*"",g' WindowsInstaller64.iss
          echo 'set build Data path'
          sudo sed -i 's,Source: "EXAMPLEPATH/MonoBleedingEdge/*",Source: "${{ env.pathStartpoint }}/build/StandaloneWindows64/MonoBleedingEdge/*",g' WindowsInstaller64.iss
          echo 'set monoBleedingEdge path'
          echo 'Finished setting installer values'
          less WindowsInstaller64.iss
          echo downloading Inno
          cd ~
          sudo git clone https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc.git is
          cd is
          sudo git submodule init
          sudo git submodule update        
          sudo iscc ${{ env.pathStartpoint }}/build/WindowsInstaller64.iss
      #Add another upload build artifact step to upload the windows installer
  release-project:
    name: release for ${{ matrix.targetPlatform }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: buildForAllSupportedPlatforms
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        targetPlatform:
          #- StandaloneOSX # Build a macOS standalone (Intel 64-bit).
          #- StandaloneWindows # Build a Windows standalone.
          - StandaloneWindows64 # Build a Windows 64-bit standalone.
          #- StandaloneLinux64 # Build a Linux 64-bit standalone.
          #- iOS # Build an iOS player.
          #- Android # Build an Android .apk standalone app.
          #- WebGL # WebGL.
    steps:
      - name: Download Artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: Build-${{ matrix.targetPlatform }}
      - name: Archive Artifact Content
        uses: thedoctor0/zip-release@master
        with:
          filename: ${{ matrix.targetPlatform }}.zip
      - name: Create Github Release
        id: create-new-release
        uses: "marvinpinto/action-automatic-releases@latest" #NOTE: If this step breaks, it may be because the latest commit to marvinpinto/... broke the action. refactor this to use stable version instead of @latest
        with:
          repo_token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" # This token is provided by Actions, you do not need to create your own token
          automatic_release_tag: "latest-${{ matrix.targetPlatform }}"
          prerelease: false
          title: "Release-${{ matrix.targetPlatform }}-v${{ github.run_number }}"
      - name: Upload Release Asset Versioned #This attaches the built .zip file to the release with the version in the name
        uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          upload_url: ${{ steps.create-new-release.outputs.upload_url }} # This pulls from the CREATE GITHUB RELEASE step above, referencing it's ID to get its outputs object, which include a `upload_url`. See this blog post for more info: https://jasonet.co/posts/new-features-of-github-actions/#passing-data-to-future-steps 
          asset_path: ./${{ matrix.targetPlatform }}.zip
          asset_name: build_${{ matrix.targetPlatform }}-v${{ github.run_number }}.zip
          asset_content_type: application/zip
      - name: Upload Release Asset Static #This attaches the built .zip file to the release without the version in the name. This is good for a consitant download URL for sites
        uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          upload_url: ${{ steps.create-new-release.outputs.upload_url }} # This pulls from the CREATE GITHUB RELEASE step above, referencing it's ID to get its outputs object, which include a `upload_url`. See this blog post for more info: https://jasonet.co/posts/new-features-of-github-actions/#passing-data-to-future-steps 
          asset_path: ./${{ matrix.targetPlatform }}.zip
          asset_name: build_${{ matrix.targetPlatform }}-latest.zip
          asset_content_type: application/zip
```

Comment: Are the targetPlatform standalones for each platform enough to generate the installers? You would need to adapt the process to generate the installers to github actions to do it at the same time. You won't necessary need the .zip files directly, this could be performed sooner (before uploading the artifacts for example). What is the step by step using command lines to generate the installers? Could you add it to the question?

Comment: @GuiFalourd I'm not sure I understand the question. The targetPlatform standalones for each platform output a complete project including the applicaiton.exe which can run the application fully. So... yes? 
Likely I would need to adapt it to make different installers for the different targetPlatforms.
I do not know the step by step command line process to generate the installers, but I will start learning how. When I have a clear idea on how to do that, I will update the question as requested. Likely tomorrow, or I may repost here if I get stuck with the command lines.

Comment: Fine, I'll wait for your return. But basically, for what I understood, you already are creating the standalone files to run the game for different platforms, so what you need to do now in your workflow, is to create the installer for each one of them. You'll probably need to follow different steps by steps and use different tools for each platform.

Comment: I have updated the post. To give clarity about why I want a zip and an installer, I want to give users the option to download a .zip file (for those who don't like installers) and the option to download a setup.exe installer to make setup predictable with regard to installation and uninstallation (and because some casual users expect installers, so it's somewhat marketing to that base).

Comment: I read your updated post, and did you know you can actually use a windows server to create your windows installer? You can create the .exe on ubuntu, save it as an artifact, and then extract it on another runner to perform what you want (you can even generate a .msi file from the .exe if you prefer to use that extension).

Comment: I did not! That sounds useful and I will look into it. If I'm understanding my brief research, all I need to do on windows is ```<file.exe> /s /x /b"<folder>" /v"/qn"```?

Comment: I've never done what you're trying to achieve, but if you've got a command line on windows which performs what you need locally, running the command on the windows-latest runner on Github Actions should return the same output.